# How to make a dict from a key list which is longer than the value list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip

I have a dict I wish to make which will be quite big, 600 key value pairs. The keys will be integers, the values will be from a list of 3 letters (A,B and C). If I generate a list of the keys how can I 'map' the appropriate value to the key.

**Code**

```
my_list = list(range(1,11,1))
my_letters = ["A", "B", "C"]
my_dict = {}

for k in my_list:
    for v in my_letters
# I know it isn't going to be nested for loops
```

**Desired output**

```
#my_dict = {"1" : "A", "2" : "B", "3" : "C", "4" : "A", ... "10" : "A"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can access the corresponding value in my_letters by using the remainder of the division of the key by the length of the list of letters.

```
my_list = list(range(1,11,1))
my_letters = ["A", "B", "C"]
my_dict = {}

for k in my_list:
    my_dict[k] = my_letters[k%len(my_letters)-1]

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'A', 8: 'B', 9: 'C', 10: 'A'}
```

As pointed out by @DarryIG, using `dict` comprehension:

```
my_letters = ["A", "B", "C"]
my_dict =  {k:my_letters[k%len(my_letters)-1] for k in range(1, 11)}
```

Comment: I upvoted, but note my_dict creation can be simplified to `my_dict =  {k:my_letters[k%len(my_letters)-1] for k in range(1, 11)}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to loop over the shorter list and the `range` object together with `zip`, and create the dictionary with dict comprehensions

```
my_dict = {x: z for x, z in zip(range(1, 11), itertools.cycle(["A", "B", "C"]))}
print(my_dict) # {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'A', 8: 'B', 9: 'C', 10: 'A'}
```

As a side note, no need to convert `range` to `list` or to specify `step` in `range` if it's 1.